# Mongodb TTL with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m struggling with getting docs removed from mongodb with the TTL method.
It´s supposed to delete docs after max 1.10min but lives forever.

Here is my code:

The model:

```
var mongo = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongo.Schema;

var article = new Schema({
createdAt: { type: Date, expires: '10s'},
title: {type: String},
author: {type: String},
year: {type: String},
abstract: {type: String},
article: {type: String},
score: {type: String},
category: {type: String},
link1: {type: String},
link2: {type: String}
});

module.exports = mongo.mod
```

The app:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sasapi');

var article = require('./models/article');

const port = 3000;
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var sasRouter = express.Router();

sasRouter.route('/articles')
  .post(function(req, res) {
var art = new article(req.body);

    art.save();
      res.send("Artikkelen \"" + art.title +"\" lagt til!");

 })
.get(function (req, res) {
    var filter = {};
    if (req.query.title){
        filter.title = req.query.title;
    }
    if(req.query.author){
        filter.author = req.query.author;
    }
     article.find(filter, function(err, articles){
     if(err){
     res.status(500).send(err);
     }else{
     if(!articles.length){
         res.send("Ingen treff på filtrering")
     }else {

         res.json(articles);
     }
     }
     });

});
```

Comment: Mongoose won't modify an existing index, so the problem is often that the index is still as it was when first created. Can you [edit] your question to contain the output of `db.articles.getIndexes()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index on that column.

```
// Expire at the time indicated by the createdAt field
article.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 10 });
```